# Prove $(\ker T)^\bot = \operatorname{Im}(T^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T$ is a linear operator.

Prove the following:

$$
(\ker T)^\bot = \operatorname{Im}(T^*)
$$

where $T^*$ is the adjoint operator of the $T$.

Comment: On any inner product space?

Comment: @Bernard yeap... on any inner product space.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we're in a finite dimensional space $E$.

It is enough to prove $\,\ker T=(\operatorname{im} T^*)^{\bot}$.

For all $x\in E$, we have:
\begin{align*}
x\in\ker T&\iff \forall y\in E\enspace\langle\,T(x),y\,\rangle=0\\& \iff \forall y\in E\enspace\langle\,x, T^*(y)\,\rangle=0\iff x\in(\operatorname{im} T^*)^{\bot}
\end{align*}

Comment: What if $E$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: I'm not sure it's true (but I'm not a specialist). $\supset$ is trivially true. My proof is based on the fact that in finite dimension,for a subspace  $V$, $\bigl(V^\bot\bigr)^\bot=V$. The general answer is it's $\overline V$, and in finite dimension, all subspaces are closed since all linear maps are continuous.

Comment: To the down voter: Is my answer false?

Comment: +1  Yeah, I'm pretty sure we need additional conditions on $T$ for the infinite-dimensional case; for example, that $T$ has closed range.

Comment: Ah, yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem

Comment: Yes – except perhaps we might consider the case of complex spaces (not clear from the O.P.'s request).

Comment: @Bernard I don't think $\mathbb R$ vs $\mathbb C$ matters here.

Comment: The link refers to the transpose of a matrix, not the transconjugate. Of course everything is valid, *mutatis mutandis*, over $\mathbf C$.